# Change the character of a key event in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText and I want to attach to it a KeyListener that accepts only hexadecimal digits. The problem is that I want to capitalize the letters and then send them to the caller, i.e return false from onKeyDown to get the normal behavior (the numbers are sent with no changes). KeyEvent has some functions for changing the action, flags, etc, but no function for changing the key code. How can I change the key code of the key event? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking control of keyboard's key-presses, try to make use of [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) over EditText to manage inserted characters

Comment: I thought about that in the beginning, but it handles the characters only after they are inserted, and I prefer to prevent them from being inserted. I may try it though.

Comment: then disable the usual pop-up of soft keyboard when EditText is touched and show your own custom-designed set of valid input buttons as a compound layout to serve the purpose

Comment: But the user can still use a hard keyboard to insert values.

Comment: you may ignore hard key-press events to handle such devices